# Not able to send message from java to Unity using UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage

Tags: c#, android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an android plugin in Java. When I am trying to return some message back to Unity using

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("testObject", "testMethod", "sample message");
```

When running the code from unity,

I get following exception

```
SendMessage: Object testObject is not found!
```

**I have testObject as game object in my scene.**

I am able to figure out what is the issue here.

One other approach I thought can work is if I can use `GetComponent<>`, but for that I have to pass the gameObject (testObject) to java about which I have no idea.

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: I have posted a post on how to interact with Unity from Android Java. Please check it [here](http://blog.ashwanik.in/2015/05/integrate-android-volley-with-unity3d.html).

Answer (score 7):

1. The name of the GameObject must be "testObject"
   Check if is true:
   http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object-name.html
2. You need to describe better. Can be a lot of things

Comment: You just saved my life... I was trying to do the GameObject class name, not the specific name of the gameObject...